# How to execute a JavaScript function attached to the href of an anchor tag automatically via JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, function

```
 <a href="javascript:firescript('1','2','3');" id="songid" class="track__number">
```

This is the anchor tag.
Now to automate click on this anchor tag to execute the href --> javascript fn using jquery

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
          $('a#songid').trigger('click');
        });
```

This doesn't seem to execute the JavaScript function. Please help me regarding this.

NOTE: The function is an AJAX query so i wouldn't want to redirect to some other page.

Comment: Use `$('a#songid')[0].click();` (I assume jQuery only triggers event listeners assigned by jQuery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$('a#songid')[0].click()` instead.

So, get the first element, and call the click method instead of triggering the event.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works.

Comment: Glad this works for you. Would be great if you could accept the answer :)